# Python HTTP POST request gets send twice

Tags: python, http, post, request, tumblr

I've a problem with my code and I don't know what else I could do to solve this or rather to find the cause.

I've started to change the Tumblr Python API Pytumblr (https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr) to support the Neue Post Format (NPF) from Tumblr (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/npf).
So I want to post a draft photo post to my Tumblr account. All in all it does what it should.. but it does post it twice. It creates the same post in my draft twice and I don't know why.

Here it starts:

```
tumblr_client.create_photo("my blog name", state="draft", tags=["my", "tags"], format="markdown", content=["URL to my photo"])
```

In another module my content gets created as JSON object (content_json), which looks like this:

```
{
"content": [
    {
        "type": "image",
        "media": [
            {
                "url": "my url"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"state": "draft",
"tags": "my,tags",
"format": "markdown"}
```

And now we get to the request module.

My OAUTH and HTTP request header configuration:

```
def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret="", oauth_token="", oauth_secret="", host="https://api.tumblr.com"):
    self.host = host
    self.oauth = OAuth1(
        consumer_key,
        client_secret=consumer_secret,
        resource_owner_key=oauth_token,
        resource_owner_secret=oauth_secret,
        signature_type='auth_header'
    )
    self.consumer_key = consumer_key

    self.headers = {
        "User-Agent": "pytumblr/" + self.__version,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
```

Here is the POST function.

```
def post(self, content_json, url, params={}, files=[]):
    """
    Issues a POST request against the API, allows for multipart data uploads

    :param url: a string, the url you are requesting
    :param params: a dict, the key-value of all the parameters needed
                   in the request
    :param files: a list, the list of tuples of files

    :returns: a dict parsed of the JSON response
    """
    url = self.host + url
    try:
        if files:
            return self.post_multipart(content_json, url, params, files)
        else:
            #data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
            #if not PY3:
             #   data = str(data)
            resp = requests.post(url, data=content_json, headers=self.headers, auth=self.oauth)
            return self.json_parse(resp)
    except HTTPError as e:
        return self.json_parse(e.response)
```

As soon as the program gets to

```
resp = requests.post(url, data=content_json, headers=self.headers, auth=self.oauth)
```

it does two draft posts.

If I send my content with Postman it does only one post - like it should be.

Can you give me a hint please where the problem could be? Do you need more code?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Could solve it on my own! :)

I implemented a request session handling as described here which did the trick. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: Hi, can you explain more what you really did? It would be nice if you could show the actual code you made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @IceTim said, you can put it on the requests docs the steps to follow:

1. First you define a callback_function:

   ```
   def print_url(r, *args, **kwargs):
       print(r.url)
   ```
2. You use it in your post request:

   ```
   requests.get('https://httpbin.org/', hooks={'response': print_url})
   ```